# Loop Over Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I'm using Google Chrome's Console window to try and figure out why I'm not able to loop over an array in javascript.

I have a javascript object called `moveResult` that looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to loop over the `MoveParts` in javascript like this:

```
for (var movePart in moveResult.MoveParts) {
    console.log(movePart.From);
};
```

I always get `undefined` instead of the actual value.  However, If I try to access the first item explicitly I get what I want, like this:

```
console.log(moveResult.MoveParts[0].From);
```

The result of this is `"b1"`.

**Why isn't my loop working?**

I've also tried a foreach:

```
moveResult.MoveParts.foreach(function (movePart) {
    console.log(movePart.From);
};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I'm trying to loop over the MoveParts in javascript like this:
>
> ```
> for (var movePart in moveResult.MoveParts) {
>     console.log(movePart.From);
> };
> ```
>
> I always get undefined instead of the actual value.

Don't use `for-in` to loop through arrays, that's not what it's for. `for-in` is for looping through object properties. [This answer shows various ways to loop through arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)

The reason your `for-in` didn't work is that `movePart` is the *key*, not the actual entry, so if you were using an object (not an array!) you would have used `moveResult.MoveParts[movePart].From`.

Your `forEach` version only failed because:

1. It's `forEach`, not `foreach`. Capitalization matters in JavaScript.
2. You were missing the closing `)` on the function call.

The answer linked above has full examples of `forEach` and others, but here's how yours should have looked:

```
    moveResult.MoveParts.forEach(function (movePart) {
    // Capital E -----------^
        console.log(movePart.From);
    });
//   ^---- closing )
```

Comment: As Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript